# Redux store: Element type is invalid: expected a string

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I am getting an error setting up the store for redux using typescript for the first time.

The error message is as following:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> ```
>   11 | // tslint:disable-next-line
>   12 | const store = configureStore(undefined);
>   13 | 
> > 14 | render(
>   15 |   <Provider store={store}>
>   16 |     <ConnectedRouter history={createHistory()}>
>   17 |       <App />
> ```

```
 import * as React from 'react';
    import {render} from 'react-dom';
    import {ConnectedRouter} from 'react-router-redux';
    import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
    import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
    import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

    import App from './App';
    import './styles/styles.css';

    // tslint:disable-next-line
    const store = configureStore(undefined);

    render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={createHistory()}>
          <App />
        </ConnectedRouter>
      </Provider>,
      document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
    );
```

My configurestore:

```
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';

interface WindowModuleHot extends Window {
  module: {
    hot: {
      accept: (path: string, callback: () => void) => void;
    };
  };
}

export default function configureStore(initialState: any) {
  const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState);
  const hotWindow = window as WindowModuleHot;

  if (hotWindow.module && hotWindow.module.hot) {
    // Enable Webpack hot module replacement for reducers
    hotWindow.module.hot.accept('../reducers', () => {
      const nextReducer = require('../reducers');
      store.replaceReducer(nextReducer);
    });
  }

  return store;
}
```

Comment: For which line do you get the error?

Comment: I added into the post. Thanks

Comment: check if one of your imports is exported as well

Comment: Why is undefined passed to configureStore?

Comment: @Rahamin not sure either, but that worked on https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot. I have been building things like it. I checked all exports, the app runs when I remove `ConnectedRouter history={createHistory()}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ConnectedRouter is for [version 5.0](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-redux) of react-router-redux. Npm currently points to v4.0.8 [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux).